# Is dragonfire inspiration a morale boost?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, bard

Is the bonus to damage from dragonfire inspiration morale and/or mindaffecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a morale bonus, but it is mind-affecting.

Dragonfire Inspiration uses the number that inspire courage applies as a morale bonus, but as far as Dragonfire Inspiration is concerned, it’s just a number. The morale typing does not apply to Dragonfire Inspiration; the damage bonus is untyped, stacking with everything except other instances of Dragonfire Inspiration.

However, Dragonfire Inspiration is a “version” of inspire courage. It replaces the morale bonus to attack and damage rolls with the dragonfire damage bonus, but otherwise it is the same as inspire courage—it grants the same bonus against fear, and like inspire courage, it is mind-affecting.

Comment: So all of it is untyped except the type of damage, which is fire?

Comment: @Simon Correct. It would stack with everything but another bard’s Dragonfire Inspiration.

Comment: @KRyan, aren't bardic music effects mind-affecting by default?

Comment: @godskook No, they are not. Inspire courage, specifically, is however. The wording on Dragonfire Inspiration is rather odd, though, so I am less sure if my answer now; good point. I am going to think this through a bit.